# 2 function calls on submit + wait for useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a form and some validation needs to happen on submit. The problem is that some of the validation is in another component(child) and I trigger it via a `useEffect` dependency from the parent component(`setTriggerValidation`), something like:

During the `submitAction`, I need to check if `isSectionValid` in the parent component(before actually doing the submit), which I keep in the context that wraps up my components. This value is updated by the child component, because it contains the fields and logic used to be validate.

```
//
parent
const triggerSectionValidation = () => {
  setTriggerValidation(true)
}

const submitAction = () => {
  // check if section is valid
  // submit form data if above flag is valid
}

<form onSubmit={submitAction} /> 


// child
 useEffect(() => {
  // validate
  setIsSectionValid(true|false)
  }, [triggerValidation])

// render component
```

I can't trigger the validation from within `submitAction` because the `useEffect` from the child will be added to the execution stack after my submit is done, so I need to trigger it before doing the submit. I can't wrap `setTriggerValidation` and `submitAction` under `onSubmit` event for similar reasons and different events on the submit button doesn't seem to work. Is there a chance of solving this or is it plainly a bad design?

Answer (score 1):

`react-hook-form` or any react form validation libraries can handle validations onChange for all fields and when onSubmit the form, it will validate all again, so y don't need to face this issue.